# calculate daily log return within a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am a newbie to R and just have a quick question.

I have a data frame with time series financial data and wish to calculate the log returns of certain columns. When I tried to do it using `diff(log())` within the table, there was error message coming up, saying the rows of the returns were not the same as the existing table.

It was because returns are always one line less than the original price data I assumed. I understand I can  calculate the returns individually as some new data frames, but I want to have the returns lining up with dates. Anyone can suggest a way to solve this problem?
The code I am using is as follows:

```
        Date   MKT_ap   MKT_us   MKT_au 
1 2008-01-02   6237    14613.57  1424303      
2 2008-01-03   6161    14587.92  1418566   


> #compute market, stock and ADR returns
> data$MR_au = with(data, diff(log(data$MKT_au)))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "MR_au", value = c(-0.00403606867795503,  : 
  replacement has 1226 rows, data has 1227
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a new column of different length to your original data frame. (The new column has one less element, since you are taking differences.)

One slightly clumsy way of doing this would be

```
z = with(data, diff(log(data$MKT_au)))
data$MR_au = cbind(data, c(NA,z))
```

Comment: Thank you djas for your answer! But I think it is not necessarily use "with" command at the first line which might make entries of the new columns including all returns. I did a bit adjustment as following:> a = diff(log(data$MKT_au))
> data$MR_au = with(data, c(NA,a))

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in one line. Your approach with `diff(log())` was nearly correct. 
Use

`c(diff(log(data)),NA)`

instead. This calculate the log returns and adds a NA to the end, because you'll loose one observation. It is important to add this to the END and not the beginning of the series.